# Google SAML SSO is not sending UserId attribute

Tags: google-cloud-platform, single-sign-on, saml, google-sso

We have an application which can be launched via SAML launch. Our customers are using google SAML launch. Recently we have observed few scenarios where SAML launch is missing Userid attribute. Upon detailed investigation we found that referrer url for failed launch is missing "from_login=1" querystring. However, successful launches having "from_login=1" querystring.
I am guessing that failed users are not signing into google and trying to do SAML launch or Somehow google is failing to read cookie because of some browser restriction and not able to send it through. Could someone please guide me on the same?

Comment: In short, you have your own application and your customer logging to this application using google SAML. Those errors happen in a specific scenario, is it possible to replicate this? Could you clarify your research? Did you follow any GCP documentation regarding SAML? Is there any error message?